# Internal reference to function created using Function constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm doing a bit of metaprogramming, using the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) to create a function from an assembled string.

The `Function` constructor allows specifying argument names and a body, but there doesn't seem to be any way to specify the name of the function.

This means that there doesn't seem to be a way to refer to the function from inside itself in a standards-compliant way (`arguments.callee` is deprecated in ES5 and forbidden in strict mode). If I were writing a literal function statement, I could just do this:

```
function myFunc(a, b, c) {
   if (c) {
      return myFunc(a, b);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this effect if I'm instead building that function using `Function()` (without using `eval()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you currently are doing something like this:

```
var f = new Function( argName, stringContainingCode );
```

then you could instead do:

```
var f = new Function( "return function " + functionName + "(" + argName + ") { " + stringContainingCode + "}")();
```

In other words, build the function inside a wrapper that returns it with a given name.

Comment: Brilliant! And it looks like performance isn't too bad: http://jsperf.com/function-inception

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable equal your new funciton

```
var myFunc = new Function( x, "return 2 * x ") ;
```

You can then use refer to the function as usual

```
myFunc(7) ; // returns, like, 9 or something
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an inner named function?

```
function myFunc(a, b, c) {
    return (function _myFunc(a, b, c) {
        if (c) {
            return _myFunc(a, b);
        }
        return 0;
    })(a, b, c);
}
```